# Binding on select html control using knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, breeze, hottowel

I am working using breeze + knockout using as base hottowel template. 
Using this template I am able to make some binding like:

```
 <select data-bind="options: $parent.rolesList, value: role">
```

Where rolelist it's a ko.observableArray() and role it's a string property. everything it's fine with this example.

My issue begin when I try make some more complex databinding, i.e:

```
select data-bind="options: mycollection, optionsText: 'dictionary().name()'"></select>
```

In this new example mycollection it's ko.observableArray()  and dictionary().name() it's "object property" plus a string property. 
If I go to chrome debuger I can see that mycollection()[0].dictionary().name() has a value.

So I dont' know what I am doing wrong. 
Here you are a short example( you can see that I am using just dictionary.name) http://jsfiddle.net/rolandomartinezg/BN2ZP/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing a string to `optionsText`, Knockout simply tries to key into your object.  It does not handle nested keys or run the string as JavaScript.

However, you can instead choose to pass a function for `optionsText` which takes in the item as the first argument and you can return whatever value that you like.

For example, in your jsFiddle, you could define a function like:

```
self.getOptionText = function(item) {
   return item.dictionary.name;   
};
```

Then, bind against it like:

```
<select data-bind="options: myCollection, optionsText: getOptionText"></select>
```

In your sample from the question, then you would just do `item.dictionary().name()` if you are dealing with observables.

Comment: yep, you right! it's works. 
As i said before, i am working with breeze and thinking in breeze. the new property should be:
 Item.name = ko.computed(function () {
                return Item.dictionary().name();                
            }, this);